# Read text file made up of strings (person's name) and weights (floats) into a list of lists with python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I am trying to read a text file with python and extract the data inside of the file in the following format.

My text file is called fileTest.txt and is set up like this:

```
Gym Students  
Peter, lbs160.5  
Mark, lbs150.3  
John, lbs145.7  
.  
.  
.  
.
```

I would like to store it into a list of lists in this format:

```
students = [ ["Peter", 160.5], ["Mark" , 150.3], ....]
```

How would I go about doing this in the simplest way. Not too worried about efficiency.

Also, with a loop how could I access only the weights to do operations and use methods on them?
Should I simply create a list for the names and a list for the weights?

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't prefer a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

a simple example that does not involve using regexps:

```
with open('fileTest.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        if ', lbs' in l:
            name, weight = l.split(', lbs')
            students.append([name, float(weight)])
```

but the same form can be used with the regexp joran suggests.

Comment: Use `float` not `int`.

Comment: @zmo as far as looping over the students list to only access the weights  if I wanted to use methods on the students weights? Can you use indexing in python when you use this syntax for example:                     i = 0; for e[0][i] in students: e[i][1].method();  i += 1;

Comment: well you can simply do `for student in students: student[-1]` to use the weight. But I don't get what you want by doing `e[i][1].method()`, as there it will be an integer which has no really useful methods…

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.findall("([A-Z][a-z]+), lbs(\d+\.\d+)",open("test.txt").read())
```

(but your numbers will be strings so youll need to call float on them)

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
   my_list = [(line.split(",",1)[0],float(line.split("lbs",1)[-1])) for line in f]
```

theres alot of other ways to do it

```
records = []
with open("test.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       name = line.split(",")[0]
       wt = float(line.split("lbs")[-1])
       records.append((name,wt))
```

Comment: I'm not sure suggesting regex to someone who is asking how to create a list is the most practical thing in the world.

Comment: please make the OP use an iteration over the file... `with open() as f: for l in f: re.findall(...)`

Comment: @IanAuld thats the best way to do what he wants ... granted copy paste wont help him much in the long run

Comment: @JoranBeasley It may be the most efficient way but but the best way is probably a way the programmer understands so if a change needs to be made they are able to do it since they have an understanding of the code.

Comment: @JoranBeasley the last example you provided is simple enough and gives me a conceptual idea of how this works. I'm not looking for a copy and paste solution but I'm taking a python course on udacity and he didn't really cover reading data from a file into a list.

Comment: @JoranBeasley in name = line.split(delimiter)[integer], the integer value says where to begin searching for the delimiter in the string?

Comment: no split returns a list ... the integer is the index into the list

Comment: @JoranBeasley when I run my code, it says that the append() can only take one argument. Is there a solution I am missing to that?

Comment: @JoranBeasley should I add square brackets to the append arguments?

Comment: yeah sorry ... forgot that

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
myfile = open('test','r') #opens the file
line = myfile.readlines() #reads the lines
line.pop(0) # removes the title line
output = [] # creating empty array for output
for i in line: #indexing through line items
    e = i.replace('\n','') #removing any endofline
    s = e.replace('lbs','') #removing lbs
    o = s.split(',') # creating a list item from parsed item
    output.append(o) #appeneding it to the output list
print output #printing
```